Can a Picklist Choice Set have filters
I have a screen flow where a user would like to select a new Opportunity Stage in a picklists. We have about 50 possible stages, but each opportunity record type only has visibility to like 7 or 8 stages.
The problem is when I make a Picklist Choice Set using the Opportunity Stage, the display always has ALL possible stages, which is not ideal.
So is there a way to make a picklist that references that field and can also filter?
My alternative is to just make each choice that they should have visible to them one at a time as different choices rather than using the Picklist Choice Set. It works, but now I have to do different ones for each record type instead of just one.
I found this article on the topic, but it is still not working for me. I see no way to link the picklist to the record in question.
https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_automate_flow_builder_filter_picklists_by_record_type.htm&release=240&type=5

If you are doing one Opp at a time, set the record type Id on the record variable before the screen with the picklist selection. It should automatically filter the values based on the record type.. I guess you can also requery the Opp which will query the record type Id which will get you to the same place.

@DanWooding I'm working on a clone, so before the screen I get an opp and then clear it's ID. I also just tested putting in a hard coded Record Type Id, and the Picklist Choice set still had all of the options. Seems like it's missing a way to tie the Choice set to the record. Maybe a Record Choice set with OpportunityStage? But Still can't figure out a filter for it.

Figured it out, thanks Dan.

The way to do this is on the screen flow, instead of just adding a picklist component, use the newer fields tab. In here you can set the specific record, which then gives you a list of fields populated from that record. And those picklist fields will have the same filters applied for that record.
Maybe it's just me, but at this time it seems you cannot access the choice selected elsewhere in the flow. Keep that in mind.
